# Android APK cannot find browser extension

Tags: javascript, android, browser, gecko, browser-extension

I am using Mozilla's android components (with their Gecko engine) to create a browser with a JavaScript extension. In my Android Studio project, the extension resides in MyProject/app/src/main/assets/extensions/my_extension/ and when I test the app in AndroidStudio using the emulator I have no issues. But when I test my app by dragging either the debug or release APKs onto the emulator to install and run it, my extension fails to run, with the Logcat message:

```
D/GeckoViewConsole: onEvent GeckoView:WebExtension:EnsureBuiltIn {"locationUri":"resource://android/assets/extensions/my_extension/","webExtensionId":"my-extension@test.com"}
D/GeckoViewConsole: Could not find extension with id=my-extension@test.com
```

I don't know if this is related, but the Logcat also shows the following error in 'release' mode:

```
E/Web Content: [JavaScript Error: "TypeError: d is not a function" {file: "https://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.mhp.en.P5JEYbZm1oo.O/m=sb_mobh,hjsa,d,csi/am=AHCCOA/d=1/rs=ACT90oFhAs9bNZoEPvKw3cywsk4r_fdSgg" line: 30}]
```

The Kotlin code I am using to instantiate the WebExtensionController is:

```
val webExtensionController = WebExtensionController("my-extension@test.com", "resource://android/assets/extensions/my_extension/", "my_browser_extension")
```

and my build.gradle (:app) file looks like this:

```
...

android {
   ...

   buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }

        release {
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel "SYMBOL_TABLE"
            }

            minifyEnabled true

            shrinkResources true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

...
```

and my gradle.properties file looks like this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? For me, the extension works for some weeks and suddenly starts reporting `Could not find extension with id {name}`

Comment: I never found a solution. I suspect the problem was something to do with how Google Play was handling the AAB and not anything in the APK/AAB itself.